# Setting ENVs to use alternate C++ installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, makefile

On my ubuntu machine, I have an older version of GCC installed in /usr/bin and the includes/ and lib/ in system paths.

Make by default picks this old installation.

Now I have a new installation of GCC in $HOME/opt/{bin, lib, lib64, include, libexec} and I want make to use this new installation by default.

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your makefile contains things like `CC = gcc` and `CXX = g++` (that is, not full paths) you can either modify your `$PATH` before you invoke make, as in:

```
$ PATH=$HOME/opt/bin:$PATH make
```

or you can explicitly set the values of the variables on the command line:

```
$ make CC=$HOME/opt/bin/gcc CXX=$HOME/opt/bin/g++
```

(or, of course, edit your makefile to make these changes)

As long as GCC is installed correctly you don't have to care about any of the rest of those paths: just ensure that the right binary is found for the actual compiler and it will do the rest.